# how to submit form using $.post without page redirection when bootstrap validation is success?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

using *bootstrap validator*; Validation On Success submit form and trying to write response in `#announcement-content` div

**Issue: On Validation Success when `#announcementpublishbtn` Submit button click Form Posted using `$.post` and its redirected to `#announcementpublishform` form action URL**

Is there anyway better way to Submit form through POST? my requirement is post form to action URL and write response in the same page `#announcement-content` div without redirection.

```
$('#announcementpublishform').bootstrapValidator({
            message: 'This value is not valid',
            feedbackIcons: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields: {
                ...
            }
        }).on('success.form.bv', function(e){
            $("#announcementpublishbtn").click(function(event){ 
                event.preventDefault(); 
                var $form = $("#announcementpublishform"), url = $form.attr('action'); 
                $.post(url,$form.serialize()).done(function(dte){ $("#announcement-content").html(dte); });
            });
        });
```

Here is my Actual HTML form

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" name="announcementpublishform" id="announcementpublishform" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                <label for="anuncmttitle" class="pull-right">Title</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="anuncmttitle" name="anuncmttitle" placeholder="Enter Title for Announcement">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                <label for="anuncmtcontent" class="pull-right">Content</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-10">
                <textarea id="anuncmtcontent" name="anuncmtcontent" class="form-control" placeholder="Announcement to Publish" style="height: 120px;"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                <label for="anuncmtdate" class="pull-right">Date</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-10">
                <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
                    <input type="text" class="input form-control" name="start" placeholder="Select From Date" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
                    <input type="text" class="input form-control" name="end" placeholder="Select To Date" />
                </div>  
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                <label for="anuncmtby" class="pull-right">Announcement by</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="anuncmtby" name="anuncmtby" placeholder="Enter Announcement Proposed by (Ex: Staff Name or Department Name or Team Name) ">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="announcementpublishbtn">Publish</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: What's happening now!! Your code looks fine though!!

Comment: I want my code to post form to action URL and write response to content div. But response is shown in new browser page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to prevent the default form submit by calling `preventDefault()` in the success event and then do the ajax request there.

```
$('#announcementpublishform').bootstrapValidator({
    message: 'This value is not valid',
    feedbackIcons: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: {
        ....
    }
}).on('success.form.bv', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $("#announcementpublishform"),
        url = $form.attr('action');
    $.post(url, $form.serialize()).done(function (dte) {
        $("#announcement-content").html(dte);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/apodtoun/)

Comment: Its Working. Whats was the Problem? how did you find?